# How to control the speed of js nav scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey Guys I found this really useful java script sticky side nav, and it works great! I don't much about js, i was just wondering if there was away to slow down the  scrolling?

```
function redrawDotNav(){

  var topNavHeight = 50;
  var numDivs = $('section').length;

  $('#dotNav li a').removeClass('active').parent('li').removeClass('active');     
  $('section').each(function(i,item){
    var ele = $(item), nextTop;

    console.log(ele.next().html());

    if (typeof ele.next().offset() != "undefined") {
      nextTop = ele.next().offset().top;
    }
    else {
      nextTop = $(document).height();
    }

    if (ele.offset() !== null) {
      thisTop = ele.offset().top - ((nextTop - ele.offset().top) / numDivs);
    }
    else {
      thisTop = 0;
    }

    var docTop = $(document).scrollTop()+topNavHeight;

    if(docTop >= thisTop && (docTop < nextTop)){
      $('#dotNav li').eq(i).addClass('active');
    }
  });   
}



$('#dotNav li').click(function(){

  var id = $(this).find('a').attr("href"),
  posi,
  ele,
  padding = $('.navbar-fixed-top').height();

  ele = $(id);
  posi = ($(ele).offset()||0).top - padding;

  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:posi}, 'slow');

  return false;
});
```

[demo](http://www.bootply.com/61276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in your JavaScript code doing that is this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:posi}, 'slow');
```

You can change the 'slow', to 'fast', and see the difference.

Learn more about the `animate` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

You can precisely control the speed on `animate` with [duration](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Here is the function signature:

> animate(params, [duration], [easing], [callback])

The strings `fast` and `slow` can be supplied to indicate durations of 200ms and 600ms, respectively. The default speed is 400ms. You can adjust your speed by replacing *nnn* with the exact speed in milliseconds you want.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:posi}, nnn);
```